# Where should I post a hardware problem question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any place where I can post questions about non-computer hardware issues? To my knowledge, Super User is specifically about computers. Is there a Stack Exchange site like Super User but for hardware? Example would be: a set of speakers that's malfunctioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, **No**

However, you can ask the more specific and expanded version of this question in the Meta site of [Musical Practice and Theory SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/). According to their Help-Center:

> usage of specific music software or hardware

is on-topic. So, a clarified version of your question **might** be on-topic there. So, maybe you can go ahead and raise a query in their meta site.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Ironically, while that's the only site it would be on topic at, the folks at superuser probably would know more about how to fix the problem, lol